# Why do I get a "This photo is not editable" message in iOS 8?

Tags: iphone, photos, ios, photos.app

I have photos in my iPhone that were added using iTunes sync with a Photos library. I do not see a way to delete them (no trash can icon) and when I tap "Edit" while viewing them I get the following message:

```
This photo is not editable
Do you want to duplicate it and edit a copy?
```

I understand that I can make a copy and edit that, but then the original will still appear on my phone and there is no way to delete it.

How can I edit these photos so that only the edited version appears on my phone?

Comment: The same for me, I was searching for the same question, do you have an answer ?

Comment: @Rodolphe Not really. It seems to be an intentional design of the sync system. The only way I've found to remove the photos from the phone is to remove them from Photos/iTunes on the Mac and then re-sync.

Answer (score 3):

If you mistakenly try to edit a photo in your Photo Stream album, you will get this message.  Edit the same photo in your Camera Roll album and it should be editable with no problems,

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The question was about photos synced to the phone from iTunes and appearing in the Photos app - so neither in Photo Stream nor in the Camera Roll.